# Run out of input when load files

Tags: python

```
import pickle
x = open("file.pck","wb")
empty_list = []
pickle.dump(empty_list,x)
x.close()
def open_file():
    open_file.file_example = open("file.pck","rb")
    open_file.list = pickle.load(open_file.file_example)
    open_file.file_example.seek(0)
open_file()
```

When I run it, it says:

EOFError: Ran out of input

I think it doesn't work because .seek is after the error; so I tried this:

```
import pickle
x = open("file.pck","wb")
empty_list = []
pickle.dump(empty_list,x)
x.close()
def open_file():
    open_file.file_example = open("file.pck","rb")
    try:
        open_file.list = pickle.load(open_file.file_example)
    except:
        open_file.file_example.seek(0)
        open_file.list = pickle.load(open_file.file_example)
open_file()
```

but it gives me the same error and I don't know why.

Comment: Do you mind posting the error string?

Comment: Please include the full traceback as your code appears to work (we cannot reproduce your error).

Comment: Why are you using so many function attributes?

Comment: I need to use some variables outside of the function.

Comment: Use `return` to return values out of a function